# Use HtmlAgilityPack to get information from web encounter error 403

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to get some information from the web with `HtmlAgilityPack`, the application was normal before I use the application to get the data from [this](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E5%85%83%E5%B8%85%E5%88%97%E8%A1%A8) page, the number of the error is `403`, And my code is as follows:

```
string wikipageurl = geturl.Text;
WebClient wc1 = new WebClient();
Stream stream1 = wc1.OpenRead(wikipageurl);
StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(stream1, Encoding.UTF8);
showhtml.Text = sr1.ReadToEnd();
```

I use showhtml textbox to show me the information the application got.

Comment: What part of your code uses `HtmlAgilityPack`?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it using **HtmlAgilityPack:**

```
HtmlDocutment doc;
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
web.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0";
doc = web.Load("http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E5%85%83%E5%B8%85%E5%88%97%E8%A1%A8");
showhtml.Text = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

If you want to do it using WebClient check **Oscar Mederos** answer

Answer (score 0):

Just try to simulate you're accessing to it through a web browser. For that, you use the `User-Agent` header:

```
...
WebClient wc1 = new WebClient();
wc1.Headers.Add(
     "User-Agent", 
     "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0"
);
Stream stream1 = wc1.OpenRead(wikipageurl);
...
```